# Typesafe config - parse from map/file and resolve

Tags: scala, config, typesafe-config

I can resolve substitutions when I parse config from string, but not when parsing from map or file.

```
import java.io.File
import com.typesafe.config.{Config, ConfigFactory}
import scala.collection.JavaConversions.mapAsJavaMap

val s: String = "a = test, b = another ${a}"
val m: Map[String, String] = Map("a" -> "test", "b" -> "another ${a}")
val f: File = new File("test.properties") // contains "a = test\nb = another ${a}"

val cs: Config = ConfigFactory.parseString(s).resolve
val cm: Config = ConfigFactory.parseMap(mapAsJavaMap(m)).resolve
val cf: Config = ConfigFactory.parseFile(f).resolve

println("b from string = " + cs.getString("b"))
println("b from map = " + cm.getString("b"))
println("b from file = " + cf.getString("b"))

> b from string = another test
> b from map = another ${a}
> b from file = another ${a}
```

When I do not resolve immediately it's visible that variable placeholders are not really treated the same way:

```
val cs: Config = ConfigFactory.parseString(s)
val cm: Config = ConfigFactory.parseMap(mapAsJavaMap(m))
val cf: Config = ConfigFactory.parseFile(f)

> cs: com.typesafe.config.Config = Config(SimpleConfigObject({"a":"test","b":"another "${a}}))
> cm: com.typesafe.config.Config = Config(SimpleConfigObject({"a":"test","b":"another ${a}"}))
> cf: com.typesafe.config.Config = Config(SimpleConfigObject({"a":"test","b":"another ${a}"}))
```

I could maybe just convert map/file to string, but is there a way to make the library handle it?

Comment: There's an issue on the library's [Github page](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/issues/76) that more or less asks the same, with explanation similar to Federico's answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ConfigFactory.parseMap` method lead to [`fromAnyRef`](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/config/src/main/java/com/typesafe/config/impl/ConfigImpl.java#L226), the relevant part for us is:

```scala
if (object instanceof String)
  return new ConfigString.Quoted(origin, (String) object);
```

It never parses the value as [`ConfigReference`](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/config/src/main/java/com/typesafe/config/impl/ConfigReference.java), so there is no way the `resolve` could work.

Their rationale could be that if you "control" the data structure then you can, somehow, leverage scala string interpolation.

---

For the `parseFile` the situation is easier. Java properties files does not support `${}` substitutions, the type of the file is guessed by the (`.properties`) file extension.

You can just use, for instance, the `HOCON` format: you just have to rename the file (e.g. `test.conf`), `${}` substitutions should then work out-of-the-box.

More information here: [HOCON](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/HOCON.md#note-on-java-properties-similarity)